# Touch ID not working after copying a user account

Tags: password, catalina, touch-id

I duplicated one of my user accounts to separate my work and personal setup and since that I cannot seem to get Touch ID to work.

I tried to remove the fingerprint and add it again, but whenever I try to switch the user account, firstly it says "Touch ID or Enter password", but when I actually touch the Touch ID, it immediately changes to "Your password is required to enable Touch ID". See the youtube link below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gqycfpx0kbY&feature=youtu.be

In some other cases it doesn't even offer to use Touch ID.

I tried to delete the Touch ID from all accounts, use `xartutil --erase-all`, add the Touch ID again, but the same issue persists.

I have current version of macOS, 10.15.2.

Comment: How did you duplicate your account, and on what type of hardware are you? Also, the link to the GIF doesn't work. As we prefer screenshots can you provide some of the errors you get?

Comment: MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017), duplicated by copying and then using `chown` to fix the rights. Link is fixed to youtube – screenshot wouldn't help as there is no error.

Comment: Since I upgraded to 10.15.2, my Macbook Pro 2018's touch id doesn't work at all.